# How to find the explicit support function of convex set?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, support-function

> Let $S=A\cup B$ where $A=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1<0,x_1^2+x_2^2\le4\}$ and $B=\{(x_1,x_2):x_1\ge0,-2\le x_2 \le2\}. $ Find the support function.

The support function is defined as $f(y)=\text{sup}
\{y^tx:x\in S\},$ where $S$ is a convex and bounded set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R.$

From here, $$f(y)=\text{sup}
\{y^t(x_1,x_2):(x_1,x_2)\in A\cup B\}=\text{sup}
\{(y_1x_1+x_2y_2):(x_1,x_2)\in A\cup B\}$$

What do I do from here?

Should I consider cases for $(x_1,x_2)?$ i.e. if $(x_1,x_2)\in A$ or in B or in both?

Comment: "S" is not convex in your question ! does that matter at all?

Comment: @Redshoes Sorry I forgot  it was a circle.

Comment: By $\sup$ do you mean least upper bound?  I'm confused because of the word "support".

Comment: @EnjoysMath yes, sup means the least upper bound

Comment: Note that even if $S$ is not convex, the support function is convex, being the supremum of an (potentially infinite) set of affine functions.

Comment: @MichaelGrant why $x^T y \leq \|y\|_2 \|x\|_2 \leq 2\|y\|_2$?

Answer (score 1):

The dot product $y^t x$ equals $\cos \theta |y||x|$ where $\theta$ is the smaller angle between the two vectors.  So to maximize $y^t x$ you choose a vector $x$ that is parallel to $y$ since then $\cos (0) = 1 = $ the maximum value $\cos$ can take.

Thus the $x$ maximizing the orange $y$ vector pictured is always going to be on the boundary of $S$.  Thus $f(y)$ is simply the magnitude $|y| \equiv \sqrt{y^t y}$ times the distance from the origin to where the boundary of $S$ intersects the ray along $y$.

It seems weird to me that you'd have to compute the actual expression for that, which will usually be some conditionals for the square on the right half plane, and a little simpler for the circle on the left half plane.

If you have to compute the explict description of it, you can find where the ray $r(t) = y t$ intersects each line in the square and similarly where it intersects the circle.

[image]

Comment: I agree with you that it seems "weird" to have to compute this explicitly. But the original question reads like a homework exercise, frankly. Support functions are useful constructs in general, even if this specific example seems contrived, as many homework problems are.

Comment: That said, thanks to your diagram, we can determine the expression by inspection:
$$f(y) = \begin{cases} +\infty & y_1 > 0 \\ 2 \|y\|_2 & y_1 \leq 0 \end{cases}$$
This follows directly from the fact that, on the right side of the plot, we can choose $x_1$ arbitrarily large, so $x^T y$ is unbounded above. And on the left side,  $\|x\|_2=2$ on the boundary, and $x^T y \leq \|y\|_2 \|x\|_2 \leq 2\|y\|_2$.

Comment: Why $x^T y \leq \|y\|_2 \|x\|_2 \leq 2\|y\|_2$?

Comment: The first inequality is simply the Cauchy Schwartz inequality. (If you don't know it, look it up; you _need_ it to do just about anything useful in convex analysis). The second inequality follows from the fact that $\|x\|_2\leq 2$, given that the left-half side of the region is a circle of radius 2.